# How to prompt the user until the input matches any element of an array?

Tags: perl, loops, input

I'm writing a Perl program where I have to prompt the user for input until the input exists in an array `@stops` I created earlier. If the user input matches then the program stops prompting and stores it in the scalar variable `$first`.

This is not my full code - I have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in my code, and I have code from earlier that puts values into the array `@stops`.

```
print "What is your input?\n";
my $first = <STDIN>;
chomp $first;

do {

    if ( grep { $_ eq $first } @stops ) {
        last;
    }
    else {
        print "Invalid stop $first. Enter input again\n";
        my $first = <STDIN>;
        chomp $first;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [`IO::Prompter`](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/IO-Prompter-0.004014/lib/IO/Prompter.pm) which offers a way to do this: `$first = prompt "What is your input?", -guarantee => \@stops`. (You can't print the exact same error message as you do now, but still, it can be useful. There are a lot of other options such as autocompletion, prettyfication, yes/no answers, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty good already, just two things.
a) if you use `my $first` in that else-block, you will not be able to check it in the next iteration of the loop. Speaking of loop ...
b) [do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) doesn't run in a loop, which is what you'd want.

```
print "What is your input?\n";
my $first = <STDIN>;
chomp $first;
while(1) {
    if (grep { $_ eq $first } @stops) {
        last;
    }
    else {
        print "Invalid stop $first. Enter input again\n";
        $first = <STDIN>;
        chomp $first;
    }
}
```

Will do that, provided that you've defined `@stops` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me - it was the "while(1)", instead of "do", and the "my $first" in my "else" block.

Comment: @B.M.Corwen if this has answered your question, then you can click the 'tick' next to it to flag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `while` in the usual way, where the `readline` is the conditional expression. It helps people to understand your code if you use familiar idioms, and it means that the keyboard is read in only a single place

It would look like this. Note that there's no need for the `if`...`else`, as the `last` exits the loop anyway

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @stops = qw/ a b c /;

my $stop;

print "What is your input? ";

while ( $stop = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp $stop;

    last if grep { $_ eq $stop } @stops;

    print qq{Invalid stop "$stop". Enter input again: };
}

say qq{Found "$stop"};
```

#### output

```
$perl stop.pl
What is your input? d
Invalid stop "d". Enter input again: x
Invalid stop "x". Enter input again: b
Found "b"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
my $str1="xy";
my $word='';
my @container=();
while($word ne $str1){
  print("Enter: ");
  $word=<STDIN>;
  chomp($word);
  push(@container,$word,', ');
}
print(@container);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are not very helpful